# How can I realize manage other Dedicated Servers by IPMI address?

Tags: ipmi

Our company have a Internet Data Center, we have DELL Dedicated Servers, if we want to manage the power of the Servers,in our technological process, we enter a special Dedicated Server of them(it can manage other servers' function over ipmi, such as we can realize power on/off/reset) to manage other Servers.

This is the *special Server*, we enter the `ipmi address` in browser, then we can login to the appointed Server by ipmi address.

to login by the ipmi address:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

control the appointed server by ipmi address:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

---

My requirement is, we want to realize manage servers' power status in our website, we want to add inputs and buttons in our manage website for control the remote servers, we input the ipmi address and ipmi username/password, who can tell me about how to realize this?

is there a script can do that? I am not sure whether we can use any script to control opening a browser then input the ipmi data, then do the upper operation.

Who can give me any advises?

Comment: You might be interested in [Managing Dell PowerEdge Servers
 Using IPMItool](https://www.dell.com/downloads/global/power/ps4q04-20040204-murphy.pdf) or [Using IPMItool RAW commands for remote management](http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/power/ps4q07-20070387-Babu.pdf). Further [search for ipmitool](https://serverfault.com/search?q=ipmitool) will also be helpful.

Comment: @U880D Thanks for your response, I tried ipmitool but get [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51948745/error-unable-to-establish-ipmi-v2-rmcp-session), no one reply yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that  [IPMI is a protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Platform_Management_Interface) and not only a graphic user interface.

Typically  when you want to integrate with your own your website , either construct **a wrapper around  command line tools** such as the generic [ipmitool](https://github.com/ipmitool/ipmitool/), or the dell specific [racadm](https://www.dell.com/support/article/nl/nl/nlbsdt1/sln311304/racadm-command-line-interface-for-drac) or alternatively there may be a **programming language specific library  with IPMI support** and you can use that to extend your website.

For retrieving and displaying current power status and other server status indicators, [SNMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol) might be a useful  alternative protocol.

Questions on how to implement such code are off-topic here.

Comment: Right, from past experience I found that Python IPMI might be a good starting point.